# Performace of multi-thread webbrowser control in ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, performance, webbrowser-control

We have a .aspx page to programmatically load page content of up to 5 urls and check each for a keyword. The following code is working but need to improve cpu usage and time performance and I am not an expert in this area

First: use of async web form to wait for the urls

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //the page won't load till the registered task is completed 
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ProcessURLsKeywords));
        }
```

Second: create task for each url-keyword pair and wait for them all to finish then proceed to return page response

```
 private async Task ProcessURLsKeywords()
        {

            List<Task> availableTasks = new List<Task>();

            failedURLs = new ConcurrentBag<string>();  //thread-safe collection of unordered items


            //start checking each keyword-url pair   
            if (key1 != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(url1))
            {


                availableTasks.Add(CheckPageContent(url1, key1));


            }

         //do the same for url2,key2 and url3,key3...etc

            await Task.WhenAll(availableTasks.ToArray());

//return response
}
```

Third: Function get content

```
  private async Task CheckPageContent(string url, string key)
        {
            try
            {
                string content;

                var browser = new WebProcessor();


                content = await browser.GetGeneratedHTML(url);

                if (content != null)
                {
                    if (!content.ToLower().Contains(key.ToLower()))
                    {
                        failedURLs.Add(url);
                    }
                }

                content = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }


        }
```

WebProcessor Class creates STA thread for each url and return the result

```
public class WebProcessor
{
    private string GeneratedSource { get; set; }
    private string URL { get; set; }
    private MyWebBrowser wb { get; set; }
    private static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

    public async Task<string> GetGeneratedHTML(string url)
    {
        URL = url;

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WebBrowserThread));
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
            t.Join();

        });

        return GeneratedSource;
    }

    private void WebBrowserThread()
    {
        mutex.WaitOne();
        wb = new MyWebBrowser();
        try
        {
            wb.AllowNavigation = true;
            wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;

            wb.Navigate(URL);

            wb.DocumentCompleted +=
                new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(
                    wb_DocumentCompleted);

            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                Application.DoEvents();

            //Added this line, because the final HTML takes a while to show up
            GeneratedSource = wb.DocumentText;
            //GeneratedSource = wb.Document.Body.InnerText;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            mutex.ReleaseMutex();

            wb.Dispose();


        }
    }

    private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            MyWebBrowser wb = (MyWebBrowser)sender;


            if (wb.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                return;

            if (wb.Document == null)
                return;

            GeneratedSource = wb.Document.Body.InnerText;

          //load frame content within page - web browser doesn't do that automatically
                foreach (var frame in wb.Document.Window.Frames)
                {
                    HtmlWindow winframe = frame as HtmlWindow;
                    WebProcessor webFrame = new WebProcessor();

                    try
                    {
                        System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(async delegate
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                GeneratedSource += await webFrame.GetGeneratedHTML(winframe.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {

                            }
                        }, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

    /*********************************************************************************************/


}
```

I tried integrating Application.Run() and message pump features but the code blocks on Application.Run()

Comment: Threads are suspended after the request being handled by ASP.NET. And `DoEvents` doesn't do anything in ASP.NET, it's useless. You should avoid to use the tasks in web applications as they are already async.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you please elaborate more on that?. I am using DoEvents to wait for browser control to complete. tried Application.ExitThread() but with no use. How else should I wait for all urls to be checked before the response is returned without using tasks?

Comment: Page_Load method is ASP.NET, right? If yes, then you can't use this scheme, as all the threads are suspended, no matter where is control histed